# How do I get an output file out of ngspice

Tags: ngspice

I have this simple netlist

```
First Circuit
R1 1 2 3k
R2 2 0 6k
R3 2 3 4k
R4 3 0 2k
Vs 1 0 DC 9
Is 3 0 DC 5M
.dc
.End
```

In the past when running a text based SPICE program I get and output file where it tells me all of the node voltages and other simple DC analysis.  How do I get ngspice to give me these values or create an output file?  I have put

```
.print dc v(v1)
```

but I still don't get anything.

Answer (score 2):

Well I found my own answer.  After fiddling with the code, reading a lot of articles on line and reading some of the ngspice users manual the code should look like this:

```
First Circuit
.op
R1 1 2 3k
R2 2 0 6k
R3 2 3 4k
R4 3 0 2k 
Vs 1 0 DC 9
Is 3 0 DC 5M
.End
```

I run the command

```
ngspice -o mine -b first.cir
```

That runs first.cir in ngspice in batch mode and produces an output file named mine.  The file looks like this:

```
Circuit: first circuit

Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000

No. of Data Rows : 1
Node                                  Voltage
----                                  -------
----    -------
V(3)                                  -6.00000e+00
V(2)                                   2.000000e+00
V(1)                                   9.000000e+00

Source  Current
------  -------

vs#branch                        -2.33333e-03
```

There is a bunch other output but it is not germane to the answer.